# Исключить один минимальный и максимальный элемент из массива

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Всем привет! 

Помогите решить задачу на языке `С++`: 

Пользователь вводит число с клавиатуры, которое будет являться длинной массива arr, затем в этот массив с помощью функций `srand` и `rand` будут записываться рандомные числа от 1 до 10. 

Необходимо исключить один минимальный и максимальный элемент в массиве и все оставшиеся числа сложить и поделить на количество элементов в массиве. 
Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int counter;// размер массива
    int max, min;

    cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
    cin >> counter; // получение от пользователя размера массива

    srand(time(NULL));

    int* arr = new int[counter]; // Выделение памяти для массива
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        // Заполнение массива
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
        if (max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
        if (min > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Min: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Max: " << max << endl;
    delete[] arr; // очистка памяти
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, у Вас изначально в цикле `for`, который заполнял массив, находился цикл `for`, который искал максимальный и минимальный элемент. Его не следует делать вложенным циклом, как и присвоение значений `max` и `min`, их следует вынести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы идете в правильном направлении, но начиная от тела цикла вы забываете что нужно делать и какой результат вам нужен.  Реально ваш результат можете получить в одном цикле:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int counter;// размер массива   
cout << "Введите количество элементов: ";
cin >> counter; // получение от пользователя размера массива
srand(time(NULL));
int* arr = new int[counter]; 
//мы уже знаем, что числа будут от 1 по 10
int sum = 0, max = 0, min = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    // Заполнение массива
    int n = rand() % 10 + 1;
    arr[i] = n;     
    if (max < n)
        max = n;
    if (min > n)
        min = n;
    sum += n;
}
cout << (double)(sum - min - max) / counter ;   
delete[] arr; // очистка памяти
```

Но не понятно для чего нужен массив вообше...

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб:

Пройтись в 2 фора по массиву, при первой встрече `min`/`max` присвоить элементу массива значение `0` и сделать `break`.

Ну, а далее, просто берете сумму элементов и делите их на изначальный размер Вашего массива минус 2.

Comment: Упражнение. Сделать поиск максимума и минимума используя не 2 n а только 1.5n сравнений.

Comment: @pavel, это у Вас олимпиадные задачки?) p.s. это не было указано в условии, но хорошо

Comment: Да за 2n не интересно, а так интересно как на это преподаватель отреагирует)

Comment: @pavel, ну, вопрос в этом не состоял, а как найти мин макс в неотсортированном массиве за минимальное кол-во сравнений вроде много раз на стеке отвечалось, как минимум [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544476/how-to-find-max-and-min-in-array-using-minimum-comparisons) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!